# How can i write less with same result

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, switch-statement

Good afternoon everyone.

Can anyone help me, im new at Coding (15yo) so please dont hate.

I am trying to do an little text adventure, in C#, but i get more then 200 Lines, only if and else if, thats really frustrating because i want much usefull lines and not everything full spammed with if queries.

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me, here is the part im Talking about
(btw im from Germany so dont wonder about my english).
I heard about the switch statement, but i dont know if this is the right case for it.

```
RPG.Inventar Inv = new RPG.Inventar();

if (Inv_Numb == 1)
{
    if (Inv.First_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.First_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.First_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.First_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 2)
{
    if (Inv.Second_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Second_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Second_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Second_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 3)
{
    if (Inv.Third_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Third_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Third_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Third_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 4)
{
    if (Inv.Fourth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fourth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fourth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fourth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 5)
{
    if (Inv.Fifth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fifth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fifth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Fifth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 6)
{
    if (Inv.Sixth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Sixth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Sixth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Sixth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 7)
{
    if (Inv.Seventh_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Seventh_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Seventh_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Seventh_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 8)
{
    if (Inv.Eighth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Eighth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Eighth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Eighth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 9)
{
    if (Inv.Ninth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Ninth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Ninth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Ninth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
if (Inv_Numb == 10)
{
    if (Inv.Tenth_Place == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dieser Platz ist Frei");
    }
    else if (Inv.Tenth_Place == 0001)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an G36");
    }
    else if (Inv.Tenth_Place == 0002)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an M4A1");
    }
    else if (Inv.Tenth_Place == 0003)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is an AK47");
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick look at your code and my thought would be a dictionary of dictionaries `myDic[Inv_Numb][Tenth_Place]`, with suitable catch for key not found...or check the key exists before accessing. your call

Comment: You should post you question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com which is made for exactly what you're asking

Comment: This logic looks like it belongs in data, not code.  You should have a file or database or something with the options and results, rather than hard coding every one.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

1. Inside your class `Inventar`, use an array to store the weapons for each spot. This way you can use a loop instead of the outer `if (Inf_num == ...)`s
2. Use a dictionary for your choice of weapons. Using that removes most of the inner `if`s such that only the check for an empty space remains
3. Yes you can and should read up on the `switch` statement. It is not needed for this code sample but in generally useful when there are many `if`s and `else if`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array with the messages in your class:

```
private static readonly string[] messagesByPlace = new[]
{
    "Dieser Platz ist Frei",
    "Here is an G36",
    "Here is an M4A1",
    "Here is an AK47"
};
```

A method to get the message:

```
private static string GetMessageByPlace(int place)
{
    if (place < 0 || place >= messagesByPlace.Length)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return messagesByPlace[place];
}
```

And use it:

```
string text = null;
switch (Inv_Numb)
{
    case 1: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.First_Place); break;
    case 2: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Second_Place); break;
    case 3: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Third_Place); break;
    case 4: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Fourth_Place); break;
    case 5: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Fifth_Place); break;
    case 6: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Sixth_Place); break;
    case 7: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Seventh_Place); break;
    case 8: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Eighth_Place); break;
    case 9: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Ninth_Place); break;
    case 10: text = GetMessageByPlace(Inv.Tenth_Place); break;
}

if (text != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```